# awk - Remove a line, if a specific column contains as substring an element from another textfile

Tags: awk, grep

I have the following tsv-file (extract):

**File 1:**

```
NC_002163.1 RefSeq  source  1   1641481 .   +   .   organism=Campylobacter jejuni subsp. jejuni NCTC 11168;mol_type=genomic DNA;strain=NCTC 11168;sub_species=jejuni;db_xref=taxon:192222
NC_002163.1 RefSeq  misc_feature    19386   19445   .   -   .   inference=protein motif:TMHMM:2.0;note=3 probable transmembrane helices predicted for Cj0012c Further possible text
NC_002163.1 RefSeq  misc_feature    19482   19550   .   -   .   inference=protein motif:TMHMM:2.0;note=3 probable transmembrane helices predicted for Cj0014c Sometimes there is more text
NC_002163.1 RefSeq  misc_feature    22853   22921   .   -   .   inference=protein motif:TMHMM:2.0;note=5 probable transmembrane helices predicted for Cj0017c
...
```

As you can see, the last column contains some identifiers (`Cj0014c, Cj0017c, etc`). Some of these IDs are saved in another file

**File 2:**

```
Cj0012c
Cj0027
CjNC9
Cjp01
SRP_RNA_Cjs03
CjNC11
CjNC1
Cj0113
Cjp03
Cj0197c
Cj0251c
```

How can I use awk (or any bash-script-tool) to eliminate those lines from File 1, that contain as **substring** in the last column, any ID that is found in File 2? For example, the second line of File 1 would be deleted, since `Cj0012c` is found in File 2 and is part of the string in the last column of the line in File 1.

I've been struggling already many hours, so thanks for any help (and, if possible, an explanation of the code!)

Comment: `grep -v -f file1 file2`  ? (I don't post as answer, I didn't quiet get what you meant by *substring* , should line containing anywhere `Cjp0` be removed as `Cjp01` and `Cjp03` are in file1 ?)

Comment: Thx for your comment! No, the IDs found in File 2 should be treated as "full words". They would always appear in File 1 followed by a space.

Comment: How are the columns of `File 1` delimited? how should we know that `Cjxxx` is a substring in the last column, rather than a separate field value?

Comment: Sorry that information was missing. File one is a tab-separated file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few options you can try - all based around constructing an associative array from the second file, and then testing its elements against the last field of the first file, breaking as soon as a match is found:

1. A true substring match

   ```
   awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {for(i in a) {if(index($NF,i)>0) next}} 1' File2 File1
   ```

   Note that (for example) this will identify `Cj0012c` as a substring of `ABCj0012c` and/or `Cj0012cdef`
2. Similar to the above, but padding the elements with a single space character either side to prevent partial word matches

   ```
   awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {for(i in a) {if(index($NF," "i" ")>0) next}} 1' File2 File1
   ```

   (you could instead pad the string inside the array assignment call i.e. `a[" "$1" "]` if you prefer)
3. (probably requires GNU awk) use a regular expression match with patterns consisting of the strings from `File2` surrounded by *word boundary anchors*

   ```
   gawk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} {for(i in a) {if($NF ~ "\\<" i "\\>") next}} 1' File2 File1
   ```

   The potential gotcha with this version is if the elements of `File2` may contain regular expression metacharacters - these would need to be escaped somehow.

Comment: Thx! I was sceptical since I had already done this, but now I realized that File2.txt was encoded for windows and not unix, hence giving some problems...

Answer (score 2):

A bit of perl:

```bsh
perl -MList::Util=any -Mautodie -F'\t' -ane '
    BEGIN { open $f, "<", shift @ARGV; chomp(@exclusions = <$f>); }
    print unless any {$F[-1] =~ /\b\Q$_\E\b/} @exclusions; 
' file2 file1
```

The BEGIN line slurps in the file with the list of excluded tokens.
The print line filters out the lines which match any one of them.

Comment: Thanks! But I find awk easier to understand than perl, but still good answer!